# Volatile objects of std::chrono::duration type

Tags: c++, volatile, c++-chrono

I do have a program which makes use of volatile-qualified `std::chrono::duration` objects. Apparently, such objects become very hard to use. For example, following simple program produces compilation error (on gcc and clang):

```
#include <chrono>

volatile std::chrono::nanoseconds s;

void foo(std::chrono::nanoseconds k) {
    s = k;
}
```

> error: passing 'volatile nanoseconds' {aka 'volatile
>   std::chrono::duration >'} as
>   'this' argument discards qualifiers [-fpermissive]

It is obvious why I have this error given the interface of the class, and I also know how to hakishly make it "work" (undefined-behavior wise) with `const_cast`.

Having said that, can absence of volatile-qualified members of `std::chrono::duration` considered to be a defect? After all, `volatile` is a perfectly legal C++ construct, and although rare in use, has it's applications.

P.S. I would like to leave the wisdom of volatile-qualification outside of this question, but my crystal ball tells me it is not to be, so to preempt all 'you do not need volatile because it is not thread-safe' mantra, let's consider the case of a signal handler.

Comment: I'm not sure I would say this is a defect.  AFAIK, pretty much everything in the standard library is not overloaded to deal with volatile.  I think this was a design decision, although I'm not sure what the reason would be.

Comment: FWIW, `volatile` is not required to work properly with a signal handler. Prior to 2011 the only acceptable type was `sig_atomic_t`. In C++ 11  you can also use various atomic types.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Except for *very* low level facilities, the std::lib doesn't really deal with `volatile` at all.  One could argue that `chrono` is so low-level that it *should* handle `volatile` qualifications.  I don't know if the committee would buy that argument or not.

One can work around such restrictions.  You mentioned `const_cast`.  I'd actually recommend casting back and forth from the underlying integral type.  It is one of the very few circumstances where I recommend doing so.  And it could be encapsulated in a little function:

```
#include <chrono>

volatile std::chrono::nanoseconds::rep s;

void
set_s(std::chrono::nanoseconds k)
{
    s = k.count();
}

std::chrono::nanoseconds
get_s()
{
    return std::chrono::nanoseconds{s};
}

void foo(std::chrono::nanoseconds k) {
    set_s(k);
}
```

Comment: I like the idea of working with rep directly. I can actually have my wrapper type around it, with volatile-qualified accessors. Nice idea, I didn't think about it!

Comment: I'd argue that `std::array` is very low-level, but it doesn't support volatile qualification. This seems more like an oversight than anything else.